# Pandoc and Tables

Tags: html, html-table, pandoc

I have some SAS output in HTML format, and I need to convert it. the output has a table, and I want to be able to keep the table format when I convert it using Pandoc. Any suggestions?

Comment: It depends on your HTML tables. E.g. col/row spanning is not supported by pandoc.